# Is it good to cache AmazonSQS object

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I am using the below jar for SQS

- aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.397.jar
- aws-java-sdk-sqs-1.11.397.jar

In my scenario i will be using the same SQS multiple times and getting AmazonSQS object using AmazonSQSClientBuilder. I am wondering if we can cache this to help improving performance.

Would caching really help , which will be the best approach to do it and for how long can the object be cached.

Current scenario

Will be getting message to post SQS on a particular event whose frequency might vary from no event to around 10000 per hour. This is the reason why i am think to cache it.

Comment: What is the scenario for which you want the sqs messages to cache ? It all depends on the use case.

Comment: I have updated my question adding the current scenario

Answer (score 3):

You should most definitely reuse the AmazonSQS instance that is returned from the AmazonSQSClientBuilder. If you're posting thousands of messages, you shouldn't need to make any other calls to SQS other than `sendMessage`.

You could also call `sendMessageBatch` if you have a lot of messages to send. However, SQS is extremely scalable, and 10,000 messages per hour will not even make it sweat so I don't think you'll have anything to worry about.

Comment: Totally agree with this answer, just wanted to add - the ONLY reason you should have for making another client instance is to use a different client configuration (connection timeout, etc) or credentials (ie: different account)